# How to get a rust-sdl2 window surface and use the event iterator at the same time?

Tags: rust, sdl-2

`sdl2::video::Window::surface` needs a mutable reference to the event pump, but while I'm iterating through the events given by the `sdl2::EventPump::wait_iter()` the event pump is blocked.

Steps to reproduce:

Create a new cargo project:

```
$ cargo new foo
$ cd foo
$ echo 'sdl2 = "0.34.3"' >> Cargo.toml
```

replace the src/main.rs with this one:

```
extern crate sdl2; 

use sdl2::event::Event;
use sdl2::event::EventType;
 
pub fn main() {
    let sdl_context = sdl2::init().unwrap();
    let video_subsystem = sdl_context.video().unwrap();
    let window = video_subsystem.window("foo", 600, 600).build().unwrap();
    let mut event_pump = sdl_context.event_pump().unwrap();
    for event in event_pump.wait_iter() {
        let mut wsuf = window.surface(&event_pump).unwrap();
    }
}
```

Not using an iterator is a workaround. So this main.rs will do the same thing, yet this one will compile:

```
use sdl2::event::Event;
use sdl2::event::EventType;
 
pub fn main() {
    let sdl_context = sdl2::init().unwrap();
    let video_subsystem = sdl_context.video().unwrap();
    let window = video_subsystem.window("foo", 600, 600).build().unwrap();
    let mut event_pump = sdl_context.event_pump().unwrap();
    loop {
        let event = event_pump.wait_event();
        let mut wsuf = window.surface(&event_pump).unwrap();
    }
}
```

This feels less idiomatic.

I do not see the reason for `sdl2::video::Window::surface` to borrow the event pump, especially if the function ignores that parameter. [Take a look at the sdl2::video::Window::surface source code](https://docs.rs/sdl2/0.34.3/src/sdl2/video.rs.html#1428-1437)

Comment: Can I use the rust-sdl2 https://crates.io/crates/sdl2 crate in the rust playground?

Comment: [Probably not](https://play.rust-lang.org/help#features-crates)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The documentation for this function does not say anything about this mysterious argument so I'm going to do an *educated guess*.

First, look at the function [`Window::surface` declaration](https://docs.rs/sdl2/0.34.3/src/sdl2/video.rs.html#1428-1437) :

```
pub fn surface<'a>(&'a self, _e: &'a EventPump) -> Result<WindowSurfaceRef<'a>, String>
```

and note that the lifetime `'a` is used in both arguments and in the returned `WindowSurfaceRef<'a>`. So both `self` and the `EventPump` will be borrowed as long as the returned value exists.

Looking at the code, it is a simple wrapper for the native SDL2-sys function `SDL_GetWindowSurface()`, so we can look at its [documentation](https://wiki.libsdl.org/SDL_GetWindowSurface):

> A new surface will be created with the optimal format for the window, if necessary. This surface will be freed when the window is destroyed. Do not free this surface.
>
> **This surface will be invalidated if the window is resized**. After resizing a window this function must be called again to return a valid surface.
>
> You may not combine this with 3D or the rendering API on this window.

The key words are those in bold. If the window is resized, then this window will be invalidated, which probably should interpreted as "if you resize the window and then use this surface you cause undefined behavior".

In order to make this wrapper Rusty-safe you have to avoid resizing during the life of the returned `WindowSurfaceRef`. This is achieved by borrowing the `EventPump`: while the `EventPump` is borrowed, no messages can be processed amd the window will not be resized.

Note that in order to borrow the `EventPump` you do not need to actually keep a reference to it, just its lifetime. By returning a `WindowSurfaceRef<'a>` anything with a lifetime of `'a` is kept borrowed.

The last paragraph in the docs, about not using *the rendering API on this window*, is achieved in a similar way, by also keeping the `Window` borrowed, with the same lifetime `'a`.